# Do any of the built in asp.net grid controls (or similiar) provide effecient data paging?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

I know in asp.net 1.0 the grid display controls would pull all the data in, and then provide paging but the paging was done in memory.

Are there any smarter controls that provide paging where they only pull the data relevent to current page being displayed?

ie. select 10 rows for the current page, instead of doing a select of ALL the rows in the table.

Comment: You talked about 1.0 that you know. Currently which version you require this for?

Comment: good point, has to be asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the object data sources have properties to pass paging parameters, which can be used to then get the subset of data that you require.

Some samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx).